# Will extern template reduce the compile time for a full specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, shared-libraries, extern

Consider a program consists of files `AA.hpp`, `A1.hpp`, `A1.cpp`, and `main.cpp` compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp A1.cpp`.

---

```
// file AA.hpp
template < int > struct AA;
```

---

```
// file A1.hpp
#include "AA.hpp"
template <> struct AA<1> { /*implementation goes here...*/ };
extern template struct AA<1>;
```

---

```
// file A1.cpp
#include "A1.hpp"
template struct AA<1>;
```

---

```
// file main.cpp
#include "A1.hpp"
int main()
{
    AA<1> a1;
    // use a1 ...
    return 0;
}
```

---

Compare this with a scenario when there is no `A1.cpp` and there is no explicit instantiation declaration in `A1.hpp`. Will I get any compilation time benefits in the first scenario? And why?

Another question. What if I make a shared library of `A1.cpp` by `g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o libA1.so A1.cpp` and then make executable with `g++ -std=c++11 -lA1 main.cpp`? Will the calls of `A1`'s functions in `man.cpp` refer to the code in `libA1.so` or they will be generated (inlined or not) in the executable?

Comment: [the explicit instantiation has no effect](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)